# Average zero values in 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I've got a numpy array that looks like this:

```
1  0 0 0 200 0 0 0 1
6  0 0 0   2 0 0 0 4.3
5  0 0 0   1 0 0 0 7.1
```

expected out put would be

```
1  100 100 100 200 100 100 100 1
6    4   4   4   2 3.15 3.15 3.15 4.3
5    3   3   3   1 4.05 4.05 4.05 7.1
```

and I would like to replace all the 0 values with an average of their neighbours. Any hints welcome! Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to [so]! We're not a code writing service, so review [ask] and show us what you've tried.

Comment: Yeah, typically, if you are asking for "hints" your question is probably off-topic.

Comment: sorry, I've tried scipy.interpolate.interp2d but the dimensions never worked out.

Comment: How do you define neighbors? `3x3` neighbourhood? How would you work with the boundary elements? What's the expected o/p for the sample?

Comment: Neighborhood is defined as closest horizontal neighbor. I've added the expected output. Thx

Comment: So, why isn't the average values in first row `100.5`, since you say that `0` is replaced with average value of neighbours? It seems good in 2nd and third row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the structure in the sample array is preserved throughout your array, then this code will work:

```
In [159]: def avg_func(r):
              lavg = (r[0] + r[4])/2.0
              ravg = (r[4] + r[-1])/2.0
              r[1:4] = lavg
              r[5:-1] = ravg
              return r

In [160]: np.apply_along_axis(avg_func, 1, arr)
Out[160]: 
array([[   1.  ,  100.5 ,  100.5 ,  100.5 ,  200.  ,  100.5 ,  100.5 ,  
           100.5 ,    1.  ],
       [   6.  ,    4.  ,    4.  ,    4.  ,    2.  ,    3.15,    3.15,
           3.15,    4.3 ],
       [   5.  ,    3.  ,    3.  ,    3.  ,    1.  ,    4.05,    4.05,
           4.05,    7.1 ]])
```

But, as you can see this is kinda messy with hardcoding the indexes. You just have to get creative when you define `avg_func` here. Feel free to improve this solution and get creative. Also, note that this implementation does in-place modification on the input array.